# Error deploying a webservice on appharbor

Tags: wcf, web-services, appharbor

I'm deploying a webservice on app harbor via git, it's url is http://inmaps.apphb.com/Service1.svc

It says that i can access the services description as a single file with this other url: ip-0a7a164f:14460/Service1.svc?singleWsdl but this one gives me a 404 error.

I try to add this services as a reference to proyect and it also throws a 404 error.

What can i do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem caused by the AppHarbor routing setup. Installing [this NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Premotion.AspNet.AppHarbor.Integration) should solve the problem.

There are additional details here:

- http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/information-about-our-load-balancer
- http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/3878-appharbor-does-not-handle-web-service-discovery-correctly